# Xml.load(_stream) in c# failed - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

no matter which xml document I am loading it is giving me the same error. I've removed the declaration, I've checked for BOM error- everything is fine- I am unable to unlock this issue:

```
    internal int ProcessData()
    {
        // xmldocument
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        // make sure there is actually data in this file
        try
        {
            if (_stream.Length <= 0)
            {
                // TODO - add error handling condition where the stream has no data
            }
            else
            {
                // check if file has an excel signature (OOXML file signature) - we only accept XLSX and .XML on upload 
                //so we can safely make the assumption here as to what to do based on the file type
                var b = new byte[8];
                _stream.Read(b, 0, 8);

                // if Excel then convert data to XML format
                if (ExcelMagicNumberString == BitConverter.ToString(b))
                {
                    // convert the file to XML
                    xmlDoc = ConvertExcelToXml();
                    // clean up the stream
                    _stream.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    // load the Xml document from the database/memory
                   // xmlDoc.Load(_stream);

                   // string _byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
                   // if (xml.StartsWith(_byteOrderMarkUtf8))
                  //  {
                   //     xml.Remove(0, _byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length);
                      xmlDoc.Load(_stream);


                   // }


                    GetLeadingIndicatorType(xmlDoc);
                }
```

the xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from> 
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: Your XML file is most likely invalid.  Can you post it (or a representative sample)?

Comment: the xml is valid. I've tested it on Xml editor. I am using the most basic one as a test and it is still causing me issues:  I've added a sample as per your request. sorry didn't mean to be abrupt - learning again how to use SOF.

Comment: Could it be an encoding issue?  What happens if you uncomment the code that deals with UTF8?  Same error?

Comment: I've tested with both commenting , uncommenting and removing the declaration (the code that deals with UTF8) and I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it. the reason no xml was loading with the xml.load(_stream) is because it(the stream) reads first 8 bites-so when it came time to call the load- it started from position 8 as opposed to position 0, hence failing to read the xml declaration or the root of the xml document. by adding these two lines prior to calling the load method, it worked.:

```
                    // load the Xml document from the database/memory
                        _stream.Position = 0;
                        _stream.Read(b, 0, 0);
                          xmlDoc.Load(_stream);
```